# FreeRTOS - Guru meditation error

Tags: c, esp32, freertos, rtos

I've recently started to study esp-idf sdk, there a lot of new concepts related to RTOS that are new to me.

I'm using a ESP32-WROOM-32 board.

My main problem concerns to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_spi_flash.h"

const uint32_t STD_STACK_SIZE = 2*1024;

void adc_task(void *pvAdcParameters)
{
    for(;;)
    {
        printf("ADC FUNCTION");
        vTaskDelay(1000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}

void app_main(void)
{

    TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;
    xTaskCreate(adc_task, "ADC_TASK", STD_STACK_SIZE, NULL, 1, &xHandle);
    vTaskStartScheduler();
    //while(1);

}
```

It runs perfectly, but if I uncomment the "while(1)" line, esp returns me this error:
Guru Meditation Error>: Core 0 panic'ed (IntructionFetchError). Exception was unhandled.

I didn't understand how the while line yield in an exception unhandled.
Why does while(1) in app_main returns error, while the for(;;;) in adc_task runs normally?

I thought that app_main was another task, like any other.

Comment: I assume that freeRTOS calls app_main and expects it to return. If it does not return, then Something Bad Happens.

Comment: app_main and adc_task are not the same thing. The scheduler has control of adc_task. But the scheduler does not have control of app_main. But I am just guessing. Isn't there some documentation somewhere?

Comment: Not a FreeRTOS expert here, but the adc_task infinite loop yields in every iteration (vTaskDelay) so it isn't a CPU hog. Try adding a yield point in the while loop and see if that changes things.

Comment: `app_main()` is not a task.  If `app_main()` is a task then you shouldn't be calling `vTaskStartScheduler()` from it.  However, `vTaskStartScheduler()` should not return so it's curious that you are getting different behavior based on code after `vTaskStartScheduler()`.  You should probably Google more about that esp32 error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to explain this first to answer the question. Meantime, my answer may not exactly represent freeRTOS:

Tasks are created using xTaskCreate().
main() is called at the start of C code from the the startup code. Startup code do not need to aware of RTOS, and main() does not belong to the RTOS.
"adc_task()" task is invoked by the "scheduler" (part of the kernel). If the adc_task() returns, the return address ends in the scheduler. The scheduler consider the adc_task() finished the given task, so voluntarily retiring, and it gets removed from the task queue. Looking at your code, that "voluntary work" is done by calling vTaskDelete() and terminating self (NULL).
So, as long as adc_task() feels like to do work, it can stay in for(;;) loop. Meantime, the scheduler schedules tasks in and out without adc_task()'s aware of other tasks.

> while the for(;;;) in adc_task runs normally?

This is explained.

> Why does while(1) in app_main returns error,

This is happening with (your version of ?)freeRTOS, but don't assume all the RTOS should do the same.
Once, vTaskStartScheduler() starts, it starts running a timer as well. The timer ISR invokes the scheduler, and the scheduler found the main() did not return, did not finish the job (by checking entry point, exit() hook, or stack pointer checking).

---

Edit,

I noticed that is app_main(). My apologies.
It looks like freeRTOS took main() into own function, that is the real starting address of user side C code. So, if you list/map the compiled output, you would find main() inside freeRTOS. This way freeRTOS did not need to do less portable operations of the hooks or stack detection.

Thus, the main() inside the freeRTOS calls app_main(), and expecting app_main() to return, restoring the stack smoothly.